# How to put a PHP form into a modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have this HTML code for a form in a modal (using Bootstrap)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-user-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">


          <form name="login_form" action="test.php" method="post" role="form">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">                  
                      <label for="email">Email:</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">                  
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>

          </form>

      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click on the "ok" button, nothing happens. This is the "test.php" file (which I only used to see if it worked)

```
<html>
    logged
</html>
```

I'm new in bootstrap so I'm not quite sure about why it does not work as a usual HTML+CSS page. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I found this AJAX code, tried to adapt it into my code but still didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input#submit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php", // 
                    data: $('form.login_form').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

By now, I just want to go to another PHP page after pressing the button (I haven't coded the login validation yet).

Comment: Show the actual PHP code that processes the form, and show any JS code you have that handles the `submit` event for the form. If you want a modal form submission thing, you'll probably want to handle the submit event, cancel the submission and perform an AJAX call instead. PS: you don't need that `action="test.php"` attribute: by default a form submits to the current url

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear, already edited my post. I haven't work AJAX before so I'm not sure if the code that I added is correct. Thanks four your answer!

Comment: You should really start one step at a time , you are trying to push things down your throat without a clear understanding of the basics. It's better to progress slow but steady than fast and intermittently

Comment: @Onilol: There's nothing wrong with being ambitious, provided you're patient enough to debug, code and learn all at the same time

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm not saying being ambitious is wrong, but there are more efficient ways to learn, trying to learn all at the same time might not be the best approach considering we don't even know what knowledge sources he is consulting, that might prove to be a pain in the A$$ ahead.

Comment: What's the core problem here? Putting the form into the modal? Sending it through AJAX? Handling the request in PHP? Sending the proper response in PHP? Handlign that response in JS?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Elias. In the situation of an AJAX call you don't want to submit the form because page will reload and you'll never get a response.

In your JS, you're binding a click event, which is good, but your `input` is `type="submit"` which will cause an issue.

First thing, remove that.

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Secondly, in JQuery you're referencing an invalid selector for the form.

```
$('form.login_form').serialize()
```

There is no `login_form` class. Since AJAX handles the request for you I would suggest using an id instead and minimizing the attributes.

```
<form id="login_form" role="form">
```

Based on the HTML you provided I have to assume you were wanting to hide `#loginModal` instead of `#form-content`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: $('form#login_form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
                // show validation error if applicable   
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what is happening, just add this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){

      $('#loginModal').modal('show'); 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: How can you _"see what is happening"_? OP didn't post any JS code, nor did he show the PHP code that, presumably, processes the form

Comment: Sorry, I eddited the question for more details. It's not what I wanted to do but still thanks for your help!

Comment: @Elias when I posted my answer there was not javascript... I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious part of your problem is that, while you're performing an AJAX call, you'r not actually preventing the form from submitting. You don't want to submit the page, but instead wait for the ajax request to end, and process the response in your success callback. Since you're using jQuery, the easiest way to do that is to return `false` from the event callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input#submit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php", // 
                    data: $('form.login_form').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
                return false;//stop form submission
            });
        });
```

jQuery's `return false` is the equivalent of vanilla-JS's:

```
eventObj.preventDefault();//do not handle event in a normal fashion
eventObj.stopPropagation();//do not propagate event to other handlers
```

Having said that, your selector and event binding could be better, I'd set an ID for the form (`<form id='modalformid'>`), and bind the *submit* event (which can be triggered by the user pressing `enter`), and then bind the handler like so:

```
$('#modalformid').on('submit', function()
{
    var frm = $(this);//reference to the form that is submitted
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: frm.serialize(),//serialize correct form
        success: function(msg) {
            //the response from the server is in msg here!
            $("#form-content").modal('hide');   
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });//your ajax call here
    return false;
});
```

I'd also check the console to make sure you're including all JS dependencies (ie jQuery) *before* you're calling `$(document).ready()` and double-check for name conflicts (in console `console.log($)` and `console.log($ === jQuery)`).
Lastly, the `$('form.login_form')` selector is not reliable: ID's are by definition unique. Classes aren't. using `$('form.login_form')` could, in theory, match more than one form. rule of thumb: classes are useful for CSS rules, not so much for JS event handling (delegation asside), if you want to handle a single form/element: use an ID.

Comment: Didn't work :( I also deleted the "action" and "method" attributes form the form code but still didn't worked. I added the <script> tag after the required bootstrap scripts, I don't know if maybe it could interfere.

Comment: @user3587175: Updated answer: you're not binding the handler quite right, also added some steps to go through to debug your issue

Comment: I added the id to the form http://i809.photobucket.com/albums/zz12/laura_bruges1/1_zpsr52nrgz3.png and this is how I implemented the script http://s809.photobucket.com/user/laura_bruges1/media/2_zpspqiluqh8.png.html what do you think that could be wrong? I'm really grateful for your help

Comment: @user3587175: In the second snippet, I didn't post the full `$.ajax` call, only the `data` key because that needed to change. You omitted critical parameters (like `type` and `url`). If JS code doesn't work, _always_ check your console for error output first (ctrl+shift+j on chromium & co)